# What happened to Web.Tests Project in startup project?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I was trying to follow the documentation for using boilerplate startup project.  and in you extracted project the tests directory only has [ProjectName].Tests while the documentation shows that there should be two projects in the test directory the second being [ProjectName].Web.Tests

I am very interested in using the integration tests that appear to be available, however the template (apparently 4.1.0) does not have the Web.Test project.  I attempted to download the Web.Tests project from the github template project, but it feels like the Tests project is now different and I'm having to jump through a lot of hoops to get it to work.

If there is a reason why it was removed, I would love to understand why, if not, what is the easiest way to get it into my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are referring to this article:
https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Introduction-With-AspNet-Core-And-Entity-Framework-Core-Part-1/index.html

**Web.Tests** is only in the ASP.NET Core template:
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnet-core-template/tree/8659b97f960a04eacdd5d148bdb48ef6f352bf97/test/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Tests

...for this combination mentioned in the article:

- ASP.NET Core 2.x
- .NET Core (Cross Platform)
- Multi Page Web Application
- no Authentication

[image: ASP.NET Core 2.x + .NET Core + MPA + no Authentication]

Comment: okay, I get that now, but why not have it included with the other 'start up' templates?

Comment: ASP.NET Boilerplate is open source. You're welcome to contribute :)