# ClaimsIdentity user is not recognized as logged in during test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to get unit testing established in a new project that I'm working on. I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate (.NET Core, Multi Page Application) with pre-built authentication as my starting point. Since [Web.Tests is not included in this template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52559572/what-happened-to-web-tests-project-in-startup-project), I am attempting to create my own, pulling from what was provided in [the ASP.NET Core template](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnet-core-template/tree/8659b97f960a04eacdd5d148bdb48ef6f352bf97/test/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Tests). I've been able to establish a `Startup` class that uses `InMemoryDatabase` for testing. However, the most basic of tests does not pass. I'm getting stuck on having a test user who is fully authenticated and recognized as being 'logged in'. The code under test is this:

```
[AbpMvcAuthorize]
public class HomeController : ProjectControllerBase
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The test is written as such:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Index_Test()
{            
    // Added as part of suggestions made by 'https://medium.com/@zbartl/authentication-and-asp-net-core-integration-testing-using-testserver-15d47b03045a'
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("my-name", "admin");
    Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("my-id", "2");

    // Act
    var response = await GetResponseAsStringAsync(
        GetUrl<HomeController>(nameof(HomeController.Index))
    );

    // Assert
    response.ShouldNotBeNullOrEmpty();
}
```

The blog referenced [here](https://medium.com/@zbartl/authentication-and-asp-net-core-integration-testing-using-testserver-15d47b03045a) allowed me to provide a `ClaimsPrincipal` with `ClaimsIdentity` using a `Middleware` class. The middleware class looks like this:

```
public class TestAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TestAuthenticationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemas)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("my-name"))
        {
            if (context.Request.Headers["my-name"].First().Equals("admin"))
            {
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "admin"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.Request.Headers["my-id"].First()),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"),
                        new Claim("http://www.aspnetboilerplate.com/identity/claims/tenantId", "1", "int"),
                        new Claim("AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())

                    },
                    "Identity.Application");

                ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
                context.User = principal;
                await context.SignInAsync("Identity.Application", principal);
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

So, what I get when I run the test is a failed test.

```
Shouldly.ShouldAssertException : response.StatusCode
    should be
HttpStatusCode.OK
    but was HttpStatusCode.Redirect
```

I think what is happening is that we are getting stuck in the `[AbpMvcAuthorize]` functionality and are getting redirected to the login page. If I remove the `AbpMvcAuthorize` from the controller, then I get a different fail state. I get a null reference error. The `View` is attempting to render and is failing in a subsequent view model when `GetShownLoginName()` is called:

```
public class SideBarUserAreaViewModel
{
    public GetCurrentLoginInformationsOutput LoginInformations { get; set; }

    public bool IsMultiTenancyEnabled { get; set; }

    public string GetShownLoginName()
    {
        var userName = "<span id=\"HeaderCurrentUserName\">" + LoginInformations.User.UserName + "</span>";

        if (!IsMultiTenancyEnabled)
        {
            return userName;
        }

        return LoginInformations.Tenant == null
            ? ".\\" + userName
            : LoginInformations.Tenant.TenancyName + "\\" + userName;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to test my controller logic, to ensure that changes to views, changes to view models, and changes to services do not inadvertently cause page load errors. Is there a way, outside of creating instances of `UserManager`, `LogInManager` and `SignInManager` in my `TestBase` class and programmatically logging in the user?

Comment: Created a repo project here https://github.com/tbuchwalter/WebTests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

1. Your `MyProjectWebTestBase` inherits [`AbpAspNetCoreIntegratedTestBase<TStartup>`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/1fa01508011720b9823bda75888221414d91a384/src/Abp.AspNetCore.TestBase/AbpAspNetCoreIntegratedTestBase.cs).
2. `AbpAspNetCoreIntegratedTestBase<TStartup>` uses [`TestAbpSession`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/eabf3c815439ec1330aee3f87d005c3e3836fe2b/src/Abp.TestBase/TestBase/Runtime/Session/TestAbpSession.cs).
3. `TestAbpSession` ignores claims.

## Solution

1. Implement `MyTestAbpSession` which falls back on [`ClaimsAbpSession`](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/a4882aec97b9167e1ac7793dad47f7322ade353e/src/Abp/Runtime/Session/ClaimsAbpSession.cs).

   ```cs
   public class MyTestAbpSession : TestAbpSession
   {
       public ClaimsAbpSession ClaimsAbpSession { get; set; }

       public MyTestAbpSession(IMultiTenancyConfig multiTenancy,
           IAmbientScopeProvider<SessionOverride> sessionOverrideScopeProvider,
           ITenantResolver tenantResolver)
           : base(multiTenancy, sessionOverrideScopeProvider, tenantResolver)
       {
       }

       public override long? UserId
       {
           get => base.UserId ?? ClaimsAbpSession.UserId; // Fallback
           set => base.UserId = value;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register it in `PreInitialize` method of your `MyProjectWebTestModule`.

   ```cs
   public override void PreInitialize()
   {
       // ...

       IocManager.IocContainer.Register(
           Component.For<IAbpSession, TestAbpSession>()
               .ImplementedBy<MyTestAbpSession>()
               .LifestyleSingleton()
               .IsDefault()
           );
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much.  You are a life saver.  Being new to using ASP.NET Boilerplate, I would have never thought extend TestAbpSession or that there was a ClainsAbpSession Class available.  You have my upmost gratitude!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. Didn't know you could comma separate the services/interfaces. How did you know to use both of the above at the same time comma separated? I was registering twice, one with each service, and it just doesn't work.